# Match 2 dates in columns return 3rd

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column of dates (A3:A89)
I have a column of text (B3:B89)
I have another column of dates, although the cells are formatted to show only the date (O6:O43)
I need to find a date that matches columns A & O.
When a match is found, I need the text on the same row as the matching date in column A, to appear in another cell in column P next to the date in column O.

Comment: After a little bit of tweaking I managed to use the first formula. Thanks very much for your much welcome help.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in column P with a formula similar to:

```
=VLOOKUP(O6,A3:A89,2,TRUE)
```

Old answer:

```
=IF(VALUE(INT(A6))=VALUE(INT(O6)),B6,"")
```